# Pushing metrics to prometheus server via prometheus remote write from netdata

Tags: linux, prometheus, netdata

I have netdata installed in one of my computers and I want to export data to my prometheus server (both Ubuntu).

But I can't use prometheus' pull system, I need the metrics to be pushed from netdata to prometheus.

Netdata has prometheus remote write implemented in its exporting engine and I am able to configure it to send metrics to my server PC just fine.

But I can't see the metrics in prometheus at all, although I know the metrics are being sent to the server PC as I can see them by listening on the port I'm pushing to, via netcat.

So I think that my prometheus config is wrong.

This is my netdata exporting config:

```
[prometheus_remote_write:prometheus_receiver]
enabled = yes
destination = 192.168.5.45:9090
remote write URL path = /write
#username = admin
#password = admin
data source = average
prefix = netdata
# hostname = my_hostname
# update every = 10
# buffer on failures = 10
# timeout ms = 20000
# send names instead of ids = yes
# send charts matching = *
send hosts matching = *
```

And this is my prometheus config:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s                                                                
  evaluation_interval: 15s                                                                

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus"

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

remote_read:
  - url: http://localhost/api/v1/write
    remote_timeout: 30s
```

If I open the page localhost:9090/api/v1/write I expected to be able to see the metrics pushed from netdata, but instead I get a blank page that says "Method Not Allowed".

I execute prometheus with the flags --web.enable-admin-api --web.enable-remote-write-receiver.

Any clue on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest pushing metrics from netdata to another Prometheus-compatible storage system instead of Prometheus. For example, pushing metrics from netdata to [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) works out of the box. (I'm the core dev of VictoriaMetrics)

Answer (score 0):

Try execute prometheus with the flags --enable-feature=remote-write-receiver.
May be you have old version prometheus and this flag will be work.